# np.linalg.multi_dot for R

Tags: python, r, linear-algebra

I'm trying to do a nested dot

```
M <- matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
x <- c(1,2,3)

m <- M
for (op in 1:1){
m <- m %*% M
}

z = x %*% m
```

result is effectively x.dot(M.dot(M)):

```
228, 516, 804
```

In python this loop can be reduced by:

```
x.dot(np.linalg.multi_dot([M]*2))
```

Is there something similar for R?

Comment: Try `Reduce("%*%", list(x, M, M))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(expm)

x %*% (M %^% 2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  228  516  804
```

As @akrun commented, you could also use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce('%*%', rep(list(M), 2), init = x)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  228  516  804
```